# Http Post localhost Visual Studio & Node JS

Tags: android, angularjs, ajax, visual-studio-2012, ionic-framework

I created a mobile app for android using Ionic framework / Angularjs, yes it's working if I use my online service, but When I try to change the URL in $http POST request, to the localhost of my visual studio  I get an error of

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mylocalhost/mysite.aspx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myIpAddress:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

I want to user the localhost just for testing, So when I edit my service, everything is perfect, and to reduce the one by one modification on my queries/code on the service for my app.

This is an example of what's inside my controller:

```
$scope.postForm = function(dataForm){
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: 'Verifying...'
        });
        var encodedString = 'action=' +
                encodeURIComponent("CheckLogin") +
                '&user=' +
                encodeURIComponent(dataForm.datausername) +
                '&pw=' +
                encodeURIComponent(dataForm.datapassword);
        $scope.errorMsg = ""; //reset the error message
        $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://mylocalhost/mysite.aspx',
                data: encodedString,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                //some of my codes

            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.errorMsg = 'Unable to submit form' + status;
                $ionicLoading.hide();
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this header in your server side should fix it.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

Comment: sorry for this dumb question. how do I add it? and you mean server side is my visual studio right?

Comment: Yes,  you would add it in visual studio .

`Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

this is how its done i think. Its been a long time since i did any ASP. I aplogise if i am incorrect